# React/Redux Application to go with Typscript or Javascript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have to do a POC for a project based on React/Redux. This application will grow later to be big and complex website.

This is important decision to take early than later I guess.

Should I go with Typescript or not. I am so confused as there are so many options these days.

Other module I will used are Material UI , React router , Thunk, Formik etc..

Thanks
Anuj

Comment: Sure, go ahead with TypeScript.

Comment: It is a very objective question, but when using `react` I would opt for [`flow-bin`](https://flow.org/) in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

as most things in coding it's a matter of choice for you and the requirements you have

if you want more strict type checking at compile time then go with Typescript and utilise the power it gives you

but be weary there is a learning curve with it and some errors are not as clear to solve as others and it will add time to development

so it's a balancing act and you need to decide if the benefits it gives you outweigh the cost of the learning and development time

Answer (score 0):

Please go ahead with Typescript.

It is suitable for applications with huge code.

- Due to the static types, several IDEs are able to offer even more predictive assistance than usual (with an instance of a class and its attributes, for example).
- Types have a proven ability to enhance code quality and understandability.
- It is optional to assign types. You can always write a Javascript code in Typescript but the reverse is not possible.
- Types make the code more readable. It helps the developer remember faster what each piece of code is supposed to do. Hence, the developer can add and change the current code faster.

Don't worry about libraries. Most libraries have a package for types as well. Eg. `@types/material-ui` for `material-ui`